# Update value in a subset dataframe using index of for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

My usecase involve me to filter a dataframe with some condition. Once I get the subset dataframe, I want to traverse through the subset one row at a time and checking for certain condition and updating a value in that particular row.

Here is my implementation:

```
> sales_data[sales_data$month == 1 & sales_data$dept_name == 1,]
   emp_name month dept_name revenue    status n_points x_partition y_partition x y
1       Sam     1         1     100       Low        9           3           3 0 0
7   Kenneth     1         1     500 Very High        9           3           3 0 0
11 Jonathan     1         1     500       Low        9           3           3 0 0
12      Sam     1         1     100       Low        9           3           3 0 0
18  Kenneth     1         1     500 Very High        9           3           3 0 0
22 Jonathan     1         1     500       Low        9           3           3 0 0
23      Sam     1         1     100       Low        9           3           3 0 0
29  Kenneth     1         1     500 Very High        9           3           3 0 0
33 Jonathan     1         1     500       Low        9           3           3 0 0
```

Now, my subset dataframe has 9 rows. So, a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(sales_data[sales_data$month == 1 & sales_data$dept_name == 1, ] )) {
#Here I want to update the value of column named x with i
sales_data[sales_data$month == month_item & sales_data$dept_name == dept_item, ][i]$x <- x_vector_data[i] ##NOT CORRECT APPROACH
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why loop, maybe:

```
sales_data[sales_data$month == 1 & sales_data$dept_name == 1, "x"] <- x_vector_data
```